# Prevent line-break in TextView

Tags: android, textview

In my Android app I have a text view that displays text containing special characters. The TextView somehow automatically breaks strings at the characters '/' and '-'.

For example, the string "aaaaaaa/bbb-ccccc/ddd" is displayed as

```
aaaaaaa/
bbb-
ccccc/
ddd
```

However, I would like to display it without any linebreaks except the one at the boundaries of the view, i.e., like this:

```
aaaaaaa/bb
bb-ccccc/d
dd
```

Is there any way to deactivate the automatic line-breaks or to escape these characters? I already tried escaping with \uFEFF without success.

Comment: try using \ before each escape char i.e. bbb\-ccccc

Comment: perhaps this post will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134457/how-to-prevent-edittext-from-breaking-a-line-after-punctuation

Comment: '\' is called an escape character..so use this character wherever you want to escape the character such as aaaaaaa\/bb. In this case you are escaping / by placing \ before. apply the same rule to other places

Comment: Escaping with '\\' or '\-' does not work, it gives an "invalid escape sequence" error.

Answer (score 5):

Keep your textview attribute

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Define Your string in string.xml

```
<string name="Username"> aaaaaaa\/bb\nbb\-ccccc\/d\ndd</string>
```

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a solution where the textView width is constant. Your answer doesn't account for that

Comment: this fixed my issue!

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this is a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22337074/3472905

I've added the slash as mentioned:

```
public class WordBreakTransformationMethod extends ReplacementTransformationMethod {
    private static WordBreakTransformationMethod instance;

    private WordBreakTransformationMethod() {}

    public static WordBreakTransformationMethod getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new WordBreakTransformationMethod();
        }

        return instance;
    }

    private static char[] dash = new char[]{'-', '\u2011'};
    private static char[] space = new char[]{' ', '\u00A0'};
    private static char[] slash = new char[]{'/', '\u2215'};

    private static char[] original = new char[]{dash[0], space[0], slash[0]};
    private static char[] replacement = new char[]{dash[1], space[1], slash[1]};

    @Override
    protected char[] getOriginal() {
        return original;
    }

    @Override
    protected char[] getReplacement() {
        return replacement;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Its is a new thing in Android 6.

Try adding this to your TextView xml layout

```
android:hyphenationFrequency="none"
```

Answer (score 4):

Android TextView follows the standard Unicode line break algorithm: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr14/tr14-45.html
Excerpt: **/** Prevent a break before, and **allow a break after**

You can work around this by placing the 'word joiner' character (U+2060) after the slashes.

Example from strings.xml:
aaaaaaa/\u2060bbb-ccccc/\u2060ddd

You can also try using android:breakStrategy="balanced" to keep the lines roughly the same length.

Answer (score 3):

this is work's for me in kotlin

```
object WordBreakTransformationMethod : ReplacementTransformationMethod() {
    private val dash = charArrayOf('-', '\u2011')
    private val space = charArrayOf(' ', '\u00A0')
    private val slash = charArrayOf('/', '\u2215')

    private val original = charArrayOf(dash[0], space[0], slash[0])
    private val replacement = charArrayOf(dash[1], space[1], slash[1])

    override fun getOriginal() = original
    override fun getReplacement() = replacement
}

//tv_text is TextView
tv_text.apply {
    transformationMethod = WordBreakTransformationMethod
    text = item.text
}
```

Comment: Solved my problem on textview with width : wrap_contents, max_width : 200dp, gravity_center, which is inside a relativelayout. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There no ready solution and no such thing as "wrap text by letters in TextView" the only way to do it in a good way is to extend TextView and modify Paint's breakText(String text, boolean measureForwards, float maxWidth, float[] measuredWidth) function.

Also, you can calculate TextView size in pixels, calculate width of one letter in pixels, then find number of letters (X) that will fit in one line and then insert linebreak after each X letters

Answer (score 0):

you probably can use the [Lines](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3alines) attribute or its counter-part method [setLines(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setLines%28int%29)

Comment: Set lines seem to work but how can I compute the amount of required lines for a dynamic text? I tried getLineCount() but this returns 0 until the view is rendered. I tried to compute the amount of required lines with the held of the textSize but I cannot compute it completely until I know the width of the TextView and the width is 0 until rendered... seems like I am going in circles.

Comment: you cant get the width of any view until its been created. If you are in an activity do your width calculation in OnPostCreate. you can get its width there. @user3190568

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the size of a text this way:

```
String text = "This is my text";
Paint textPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
textPaint.setTextSize(14.0f);
Rect bounds = new Rect();
textPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);

bounds.width() // width in pixels
bounds.height() // height in pixels
```

Based on these values you could break up the text in pieces and insert newline characters.

Answer (score -1):

I have tested the following code. You can even convert it into a function:

```
    String specialString = "a/b/-c/d-d";
    String[] specialArray = specialString.split("/");
    String str = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < specialArray.length - 1; i++){
        str = str + specialArray[i] + Character.toString((char) 47);
    }
    str = str + specialArray[specialArray.length - 1];
    specialArray = str.split("-");
    str = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < specialArray.length - 1; i++){
        str = str + specialArray[i] + Character.toString((char) 45);
    }
    str = str + specialArray[specialArray.length - 1];
    textView.setText(str);
```

Now the text does not escape