# TextView new line (in multiline) issues

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, multiline

currently I am getting this result for a multiLine text view -

```
maxLines = 2
```

If text is -

> Hello hfhfhfhfhfhfhhfhfhfhfhfhhfhfhf

Then output is :

[image]

But I need it like this :

[image]

Please help me to get this result :)

XML is

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_name"
            style="@style/default_text_font_face"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:text="Hello hffffffhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhhfhfhhfhfhfhfhhfhfhfhhfhfhfhfhhfhfhfhfhhfhfhfhfhhfhfhfhfhhfhf"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

Comment: Use Hello hhhhhhhhhhhhh\nhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh...

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @NehaK see my answer below.

Comment: maybe it will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289161/word-wrap-break-word-in-edittext/22337074#22337074

Comment: show your xml here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have use below property..

```
android:maxWidth="size"
```

Replace the `size` with the size you prefer. For example, `100dip`.

**UpDate :**

xml file

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:maxWidth="50dip"
        android:text="Best Efffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
```

Output :

[image]

**UpDate 2 :**

using `match_parent`.

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:maxWidth="50dip"
            android:text="Best Efffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
```

output :

[image]

Comment: with your code and I test it in Nexus4 Preview, the result is different

Comment: thank you for correct me, I will check it later because now I don't have real device ;)

Comment: But I need to make it matchParent this is my requirement

Comment: @NehaK see my update answer...UpDate 2.. But Keep in mind whenever you are using `match_parent` your textlength is more ...

Comment: I want it from right side means when gravity is right or end, and for that it givng same result

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

to your `TextView`

**EDIT1**

Try the following way

```
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#535353"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:text="Best Effffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff\nfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff"
    android:textSize="20dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

> Output

[image: answer]

I hope this may helps you