# Non-breaking TextView in Android

Tags: android, textview

I've been looking for a solution to this problem for a long time now, but it doesn't seem to be possible. My question is basically the same as these ones:

- [Prevent Android's TextView from breaking links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23622005/prevent-androids-textview-from-breaking-links)
- [Prevent line-break in TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21094349/prevent-line-break-in-textview)

But since they are 8 years old I'm asking again in the hope that there's a non-hacky solution nowadays.

I want to display an url in a multiline TextView. The url should fill the whole width, without breaking/wrapping.

So instead of this:

```
|http://www.example.com/  |
|somepath/something/      |
|foobar/helloworld        |
```

It should look like this:

```
|http://www.example.com/so|
|mepath/something/foobar/h|
|elloworld                |
```